# Can we have asymmetric grid view extended with grid view?

Tags: android

I have an asymmetric grid view, height can vary in each cell of the grid view but when I call

```
gv_location.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (firstVisibleItem > 0) {

            bt_topShiftLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            srl_locationRefresh.setEnabled(false);

        } else {

            srl_locationRefresh.setEnabled(true);
            bt_topShiftLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }
});
```

firstVisibleItem has always had 0 in it.

So, Can i have asymmetric grid view extended with grid view?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve variable cell sized grid view using recyclerview http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/material/lists-cards.html and StaggeredGridLayoutManager https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: Thanks Pavan, But I don't want to use recyclerview as it conflicts with other libraries I am using